# Why static method in parent class don't get sub class name?

Tags: java

like,

```
class Parent {
    //This is write 'Sub'
    getClass().getName();

}


class Sub extends Parent{

}
```

But, I wonder this,

```
 class Parent {
    public static void print(){
        //How to get sub class name?
    }
}


class Sub extends Parent{
    print();
}
```

I search that, 
In Java, static method in parentClass don't called subClass name.

Why? 'why don't called?'

Thanks.

Comment: I read the question twice and I really couldn't comprehend anything at all. Please improve your question and clearly state what the problem is.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot: static members belong to classes rather than instances.

Answer (score 2):

Static member come in scope when class loads so it is clear that you can not assosiate these with instance.